# LINQ2Entities with MySQL on Mono

Tags: mono, linq-to-entities, mysql-connector

I'm trying to run a LINQ2Entities sample (MySQL connector 6.3.6) on Mono 2.8.2 (compiled from source, Ubuntu 10.10). I get following error:

```
$mono L2EMySQL.exe
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it Mono that is not supporting LINQ2Entities? If so, is there any plan to support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono does not supply an implementation of the Entity Framework, and (currently) has no plans to implement it in the near future, due to the abundance of high-quality and cross-platform ORM frameworks already in existence for the CLR.  [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) and [LINQ to SQL](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/), for example.

(This is not speculation and was overheard in #mono coming from one of the Mono team members.)

---

**Update 2012-10-03:** Microsoft has released EF under the Apache 2.0 license ([source](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/microsoft-open-sources-entity-framework-198213)), and the Mono project bundles it starting with version 2.11.3 (which is an alpha release at the time of this writing).

Comment: I have added a couple to my answer -- NHibernate being the other one that comes to mind right away.  There are others, but I can't think of them off the top of my head.

Comment: The Linq-to-SQL implementation that ships with Mono supports SQL Server, as well as MySQL, PostgreSQL, and several other databases.  This is not an obsolete answer; the Mono project's stance on EF has not changed.

Comment: Ah, that's why -- this changed recently.  MS appears to have released EF under an open-source license, and it will be bundled with Mono 2.11.3.  (Not that right now, 2.11.3 is an alpha version of Mono, so this answer is not yet obsolete, but will be soon.)